# Jboss 7.1 Final not deploying my war

Tags: java, web-applications, deployment, jboss, jboss7.x

**this is the error log i am getting**  **i have highlighted the error also ..any solution to solve it?**

```
16:54:56,184 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."hello.war".STRUCTURE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."hello.war".STRUCTURE: Failed to process phase STRUCTURE of deployment "hello.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_20]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_20]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_20]
Caused by: **org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS018037: Failed to process WEB-INF/lib: "/C:/Share/Jboss/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/bin/content/hello.war/WEB-INF/lib/activation-1.1.jar"**
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WarStructureDeploymentProcessor.deploy(WarStructureDeploymentProcessor.java:120)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 5 more
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS018037: Failed to process WEB-INF/lib: "/C:/Share/Jboss/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/bin/content/hello.war/WEB-INF/lib/activation-1.1.jar"
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WarStructureDeploymentProcessor.createWebInfLibResources(WarStructureDeploymentProcessor.java:175)
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WarStructureDeploymentProcessor.createResourceRoots(WarStructureDeploymentProcessor.java:153)
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WarStructureDeploymentProcessor.deploy(WarStructureDeploymentProcessor.java:114)
    ... 6 more

**Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file**
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_20]
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_20]
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_20]
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_20]
    at org.jboss.vfs.spi.JavaZipFileSystem.<init>(JavaZipFileSystem.java:97)
    at org.jboss.vfs.spi.JavaZipFileSystem.<init>(JavaZipFileSystem.java:83)
    at org.jboss.vfs.VFS.mountZip(VFS.java:408)
    at org.jboss.vfs.VFS.mountZip(VFS.java:434)
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WarStructureDeploymentProcessor.createWebInfLibResources(WarStructureDeploymentProcessor.java:170)
    ... 8 more
```

Comment: I once saw this kind of error in Tomcat because the directories used to write temporal files where missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have a corrupt `activation.war` file in your WAR. Also, don't include the `activation.war`. That library will be included from the server.

Answer (score 0):

It's truly unbelievable that since v5 this issue still isn't solved. We have it all the time when hot-deploying and the war/ears are perfectly okay. Getting frustrated here! Never had this with Weblogic.